# libffmpeg: writing an RTSP stream to an output file

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I'm working with libffmpeg in an iOS app. My goal is to connect to an RTSP source and write the media out to a file that can later be used with the iOS media player. Ideally I'd like to do this without transcoding the incoming data. I also want to be able to later re-encode the media with AVAssetExportSession if the user chooses to do so.

Because I want to create a file that is compatible with iOS, I'm limited (I believe) to mpeg, mp4 or quicktime (mov) formats.

Whenever I try to use one of these formats, I see the following warnings during my call to avformat_write_header:

[mov @ 0x16401c00] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mov @ 0x16401c00] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers

My understanding is that the header wants to know the ultimate file size, which I do not know (the RTSP server is live streaming a camera, and the user stops the recording whenever they want). I guess that makes sense, but I know that others have successfully done this using the ffmpeg command line, so I'm confused as to what else I need to do here.

If I ignore the warning, I can still proceed with writing the file. If I choose mpeg or mp4 formats, my app crashes when I call av_write_trailer. If I use mov, I can successfully close the file, and the file does play back, but usually fails when I try to hand it to the AVAssetExportSession.

I would appreciate any insight into this. Thanks.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

I found what appears to be a solution -- at least, it eliminates the warning. I had to set the CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER on both the audio and video codecs, before calling avcodec_open2.